# Does Python Pulsar-Client SDK supports pulsar admin based classes?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-pulsar, python-pulsar

Hi I was looking to fetch metadata of pulsar topics using python-client sdk provided by pulsar.

But i got stuck as , i was not able to find any classes regarding pulsar-admin actions like getting topics , there schema , stats etc.

Though the same things are available in java admin sdk.
example

```
In java :-

String namespace = "my-tenant/my-namespace";
admin.topics().getList(namespace);
```

link to doc :- https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/next/admin-api-topics

i need to get same set of functionally  but in python sdk.

is there any way to do this or yet not supported.

Solutions Tried :-

i have tried the pulsar admin rest api's and they work.. but i prefer to go via sdk path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python SDK does not have that yet.

You potentially could build a Python SDK using OpenAPI/Swagger which is available here https://pulsar.apache.org/admin-rest-api/

You could also make REST calls from Python.

You can make a request for this functionality:   https://github.com/apache/pulsar/issues/new/choose

The full current documentation is here:   https://pulsar.apache.org/api/python/